# If someone A has lung cancer

Tags: cancer

and the lung cancer has not spreaded to other parts of A, does transplant help to remove cancer?

If someone B transplants a lung 'contaminated' by cancer, does B necessarily get cancer too? His body may kill cancer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard procedure for curing cancer (besides chemotherapy) is to surgically remove parts of the organ with the tumor in it (or the whole, depending where it occurs). You also keep some safety margin around the tumor to be sure you definitely removed it. But in principle removing the organ in which the tumor grows and transplanting a healthy one would help.

There is indeed a problem with tumor cells in transplanted organs. If small (and thus undetectable) tumors have formed in these organs, they will be transplanted with the organ. Since the patient receives high doses of immunosuppressing drugs to avoid a reaction of the patients immune system, the activity of the immune system is greatly reduced.

Since the immune system also plays an important role in detecting (and fighting) the malignant cells of a cancer, this is also reduced which favors the appearance of tumors. There are reports for example from cystic fibrosis patients who received a lung transplant from a smoker and later died of lung cancer (see [here](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/health/news/9747532/Death-of-transplant-patient-reveals-that-four-in-ten-lungs-come-from-donors-who-smoke.html), at the moment I only have a news source for it).

Answer (score 3):

To the best of my knowledge, the only solid organ neoplasm routinely treated by Tx, at the moment, is hepatocellular carcinoma (liver), and even that under very strict conditions. For the rest, transplantation is currently not a standard therapy because of the very real possibility of accelerated growth of micrometastases under severe imunosuppression after the transplant.

And yes... a tumour transplanted into a person would grow, and fast, again because of immunosuppression.

If you're asking this for a practical reason, I'd advise you to talk to the oncologist involved in treatment for a thorough explanation of why this wouldn't work / referral to an applicable study, if there is one.